# Saving charts in Excel sheets

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to know is it possible to save bargraph,piechart developed using jfreechart in excel sheet directly.If possible can anyone guide as to how this can be done.I know that using jfreechart we can save bargraph,piechart in .png,jpeg format but is it possible to directly save it in excel sheet.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible using JFreeChart only. However, you can create and manipulate Microsoft Office documents using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).